# Storyboard bug: everything is squashed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

So I clicked on my storyboard in Xcode today and all of my controllers were squashed. I dragged out an empty ViewController on the left for comparison. Has anyone else encountered this? [image: storyboard screenshot]

Comment: I think the storyboard file was corrupted somehow. I checked out a previous revision and it is back to normal. Fortunately, I commit frequently and did not lose much work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue again. It appears to be a bug related to segues that loop back to the initial view controller. If I delete the segue, the view returns to normal (non-squashed). When I add the segue again, everything appears normal until you reopen the project. The solution I eventually came up with was to embed the initial view controller in a nav controller. Now the loop back segue no longer points to the initial view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the image, it's landscape rather than being squashed.  This happened to be when I refactored a class name from default `FirstViewController` to something sensible.

When I had this I did the following -

- In `MYPROJECT-Info.plist` - change the 'Supported interface orientations' to being portrait. (you might see the first one as landscape)

Then I re-did the refactor, and as if by magic the storyboard was fixed.

I guess some actions cause the storyboard to be *recalculated* and it uses the first item in the plist to decide how to show the view.